# Dividing a signal in channels

Tags: time-frequency, multi-channel

I have a signal in time domain, and I have to convert it into frequency domain and divide it into 100 channels, and find the center frequency of each channel.

I am not good in "MATLAB" so how to do that, help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should try stack overflow for help with the coding